# Adding a header file to Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, cs50

I'm trying to add a C library to Xcode. I downloaded the library from an online C class, and the zipped file contains two files: `cs50.c` and `cs50.h`.

I installed these files using the following commands:

```
gcc -c -ggdb -std=c99 cs50.c -o cs50.o
ar rcs libcs50.a cs50.o
rm -f cs50.o
chmod 0644 cs50.h libcs50.a
sudo mv cs50.h /usr/include
sudo cp libcs50.a /usr/lib
```

When building the project, I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GetString", referenced from:
_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is how I'm referencing the header file in my program:

```
#include </usr/include/cs50.h>
```

If I don't include the path, I get a *can't find file* message.

My version of Xcode is: Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) and I'm running OS X 10.7.5.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Update:

[image: Actual Error Message]

[image: Added -lcs50 to the build phase]

Comment: Did you add `-lcs50` to the linker options? And what is the exact error message you get for `#include "cs50.h"`?

Comment: I'd just add the files to the Xcode project and have it do the build, unless they need some weird build environment.  Move them into your project directory structure, then, on the appropriate folder in Xcode, RMB and select "add existing files" or some such.

Comment: Yes, I have added -lcs50. I uploaded a screenshot of what I've done and the actual error message.

Comment: It would probably have helped a ton to add the `-lcs50` to the **link** compiler flags and not the **compile** flags of your source file.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should never install or modify anything in `/usr` unless you have a very good reason to do so.  This directory is reserved for the operating system, and you can quickly run into a lot of problems - for instance if you accidentally overwrite a system library or header file and even installing new things in there may cause problems when updating your operating system.

If you really need to install this system-wide, then put it into `/usr/local`.

However, since you compiled the library with debugging information, I assume that you also want to test and play around with it in your project.

To do that, it's much easier to add the sources as a new "C/C++ Library" target to your project.  Then Xcode will take care of all the ugly details such as compiling, choosing the right processor architecture (32 or 64 bit), you'll get source-level debugging support in Xcode and if you ever want to install your app or create a package for it, then Xcode will also automatically bundle the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to use gcc to compile the cs50.h library, I have found that to be unsuccessful on most modern 64 bit macs.  Xcode 4.x generally wants a 64 bit compatible library format.  GCC has not been updated to include 64 bit object files.  Clang/LLVM is a rising alternative to gcc, and is used by Apple for Xcode as their preferred compiler engine.  I have not personally tried it yet, but will be exploring Xcode to produce a compatible library for Xcode.  I am taking the Harvardx cs50x course at edX, and it is great course, even for experienced programmers.  The cs50.h library is interesting, because it provides relatively robust I/O routines for various variable types, e.g. String, Integer. float for the c programming language, including good protection for buffer overflow attacks.
  You are actually building a custom dynamic library to be added to Xcode, which is also known as a framework.  If you have apple developer account, check out the framework programming guide, it should prove useful.

Comment: "GCC has not been updated to include 64 bit object files" Sorry?